# Name Problems when running linear model and waldtest in function environment

Tags: r, lm

I have a problem trying to encapsulate a linear model and `waldtest` in a function. When you run the wald test it can no longer tell where the data is. This happens both when the `lm` and `waldtest` are in the same function and when the `lm` is in a function and `waldtest` is in the global (or a different function) environment.

### Minimal working example

```
# Loading Packages
library(lmtest)
# Loading Data
x <- sin(1:100)
y <- 1 + x + rnorm(100)
dd = data.frame(x = x, y = y)
form = "y ~ x"
```

When I do the regression and waldtest outside a function there is no problem:

```
# Doing Regression outside function
Model1 = lm(formula = form, data = dd)
waldtest(Model1)
```

When I do the regression and waldtest inside a function there are errors:

```
# Doing Regression inside function
reg = function(form, FrameOfData){
  Model = lm(formula = form, data = FrameOfData)
  print(waldtest(Model))
}
reg(form, FrameOfData = dd)
# Error in is.data.frame(data) : object 'FrameOfData' not found
```

Changing the above waldtest command to `print(waldtest(Model2, data = dd))` is also unsuccessful returning `# Error in modelUpdate(objects[[i - 1]], objects[[i]]) : original model was of class "lm", updated model is of class "data.frame"`

The one workaround I can find is to choose a global dataframe name to match the function name (in the above case run `FrameOfData = dd` before running `reg` function) but I don't want to do this for the application I have in mind.

### Other questions on Stack Overflow

The most similar question I can find is this one:
[Regression with Heteroskedasticity Corrected Standard Errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4385436/regression-with-heteroskedasticity-corrected-standard-errors)
where this problem does not arise as the linear regression is run in the global environment.

### Desired Solution

Is there anyway to run the `lm` command and then change the object's attributes to point to the global dataframe's true name? Otherwise is there a way to tell the `waldtest` command the global dataframe's true name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1) do.call** In function `reg` replace the line that defines `Model` with:

```
Model <- do.call("lm", list(formula = form, data = FrameOfData))
```

**1a)** A variation:

```
Model <- do.call("lm", list(formula = form, data = substitute(FrameOfData)))
```

**2) with** Alternately, this would work:

```
Model <- with(FrameOfData, lm(formula = form))
```

**3) eval** Yet another possibility is this:

```
Model <- eval(substitute(lm(formula = form, data = FrameOfData)))
```

although using `eval` tends to be frowned upon.

**3a)** Here is a variation:

```
reg <- function(form, FrameOfData) {
  eval(substitute(waldtest(lm(formula = form, FrameOfData)), 
         list(form = form, FrameOfData = FrameOfData)))
}
```

**Note:** There are potential problems with most of the above.  The following based on (1) should work and (3a) works in this case too but the corresponding code for all the others will fail:

```
set.seed(123)

rm(x, y, dd, form)

fn <- function() {
    x <- sin(1:100)
    y <- 1 + x + rnorm(100)
    dd = data.frame(x = x, y = y)
    form = "y ~ x"
    reg(form, FrameOfData = dd)
}

reg <- function(form, FrameOfData){
  Model <- do.call("lm", list(formula = form, data = FrameOfData))
  waldtest(Model)
}
fn()
```

Comment: Great answer thank you. I think `with` and `eval` are the best - `do.call` copies the whole data.frame to the Model object. If I return it from the function it is larger (as per `object.size`)

Comment: 1a) fixes this problem for `do.call`

Comment: So *why* does the problem occur?

Comment: It's R's scope rules. If you copy the inputs then you don't depend on them.