# Using abstract formula with emmeans

Tags: r, functional-programming, formula, emmeans

I'm using `emmeans` to get adjusted means with a log transformation.

But unexpectedly, when I try to call this with a custom function, the behaviour is quite different with no explicit warning (except the one about the log transformation).

Here is a reproducible example:

```
db = mtcars %>% mutate(cyl=factor(cyl))
m = lm(log(mpg) ~ log(disp) + cyl, data = db)
print(m$call)
emm = emmeans(m, spec = "cyl", type = "response")
as.data.frame(emm)

f = function(formula){
  m = lm(formula, data = db)
  print(m$call)
  emm = emmeans(m, spec = "cyl", type = "response")
  as.data.frame(emm)
}
f(log(mpg) ~ log(disp) + cyl)
```

Here, the only difference between the models inside and outside the function is the `call` object (tested with `all.equal()`). They give exact same results otherwise.

This code is not mine and I'm only trying to automatize it, assuming the "outside function" output is correct.

Why is the output different? How can I automatize an `emmeans` call?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/36228342/4241780

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36228342/4241780), this can also be done using `do.call`.

```r
db = dplyr::mutate(mtcars, cyl=factor(cyl))

f <- function(formula){
  m = do.call(lm, list(formula = formula, data = db))
  print(m$call$formula)
  emm = emmeans::emmeans(m, spec = "cyl", type = "response")
  as.data.frame(emm)}

f(log(mpg) ~ log(disp) + cyl)
#> log(mpg) ~ log(disp) + cyl
#>   cyl response       SE df lower.CL upper.CL
#> 1   4 18.59940 1.847377 28 15.17535 22.79603
#> 2   6 17.71003 1.011478 28 15.75472 19.90802
#> 3   8 17.71054 1.020718 28 15.73839 19.92981
```

<sup>Created on 2021-07-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

This is a scoping issue (formulas have an associated environment that depends on how/where they are created). You could insert the formula into the `lm` call by computing on the language:

```
f = function(formula){
  m = eval(bquote(lm(.(formula), data = db)))
  print(m$call)
  emm = emmeans(m, spec = "cyl", type = "response")
  as.data.frame(emm)
}
```