# R plm thinks my number vector is a factor, why?

Tags: r, plm

With this data input:

```
A   B   C   D
0.0513748973337 0.442624990365  0.044669941640565   12023787.0495
-0.047511808790502  0.199057057555  0.067542653775225   6674747.75598
0.250333519823608   0.0400359422093 -0.062361320324768  10836244.44
0.033600922318947   0.118359141703  0.048493523722074   7521473.94034
0.00492552770819    0.0851342003243 0.027123088894137   8742685.39098
0.02053037069955    0.0535545969759 0.06352586720282    8442677.4204
0.09050961131549    0.044871795257  0.049363888991624   7223126.70424
0.082789930841618   0.0230375009412 0.090676778601245   8974611.5623
0.06396481119371    0.0467280364963 0.128097065131764   8167179.81463
```

and this code:

```
library(plm);
mydata <- read.csv("reproduce_small.csv", sep = "\t");
plm(C ~ log(D), data = mydata, model = "pooling"); # works
plm(A ~ log(B), data = mydata, model = "pooling"); # error
```

the second `plm` call returns the following error:

```
Error in Math.factor(B) : ‘log’ not meaningful for factors
```

`reproduce_small.csv` contains the ten lines of data pasted above. Obviously, `B` is not a factor, it is clearly a numeric vector. This means that `plm` thinks it is a factor. The questions are "why?", but more importantly "how do I fix this?"

Things I've tried:

#1) `mydata$B.log <- log(mydata$B)` results in

```
Error in model.frame.default(formula = y ~ X - 1, drop.unused.levels = TRUE) : 
  variable lengths differ (found for 'X')
```

which is in itself weird, since A and B.log have clearly the same length.

#2) `plm(A ~ log(D), data = mydata, model = "pooling");` results in the same error as #1.

#3) `plm(C ~ log(B), data = mydata, model = "pooling");` results in the same original error (log not meaningful for factors).

#4) `plm(A ~ log(B + 1), data = mydata, model = "pooling");` results in

```
Error in `contrasts<-`(`*tmp*`, value = contr.funs[1 + isOF[nn]]) : 
  contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels
In addition: Warning message:
In Ops.factor(B, 1) : ‘+’ not meaningful for factors
```

#5) `plm(A ~ as.numeric(as.character(log(B))), data = mydata, model = "pooling");` results in the same original error (log not meaningful for factors).

EDIT: As suggested, I'm including the result of `str(mydata)`:

```
> str(mydata)
'data.frame':   9 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ A: num  0.05137 -0.04751 0.25033 0.0336 0.00493 ...
 $ B: num  0.4426 0.1991 0.04 0.1184 0.0851 ...
 $ C: num  0.0447 0.0675 -0.0624 0.0485 0.0271 ...
 $ D: num  12023787 6674748 10836244 7521474 8742685 ...
```

Also trying `mydata <- read.csv("reproduce_small.csv", sep = "\t", stringsAsFactors = FALSE);` didn't work.

Comment: Did you try coercing it into a numeric? maybe read.csv considers it a character vector and makes a factor out of it

Comment: Please show `str(mydata)`

Comment: > str(mydata)
   'data.frame': 9 obs. of  4 variables:
    $ A: num  0.05137 -0.04751 0.25033 0.0336 0.00493 ...
    $ B: num  0.4426 0.1991 0.04 0.1184 0.0851 ...
    $ C: num  0.0447 0.0675 -0.0624 0.0485 0.0271 ...
    $ D: num  12023787 6674748 10836244 7521474 8742685 ...

Comment: use `str(yourdatafile)` to check the structure. and also try to use `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` when reading data from `csv` file.

Comment: OK, yes I can reproduce. The fault is definitely not with reading in the data. Seems very strange.

Comment: @Zico `mydata <- read.csv("reproduce_small.csv", sep = "\t", stringsAsFactors = FALSE);` doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: Also note that fitting `C ~ B` gives you coefficients as if `B` is a factor, but `as.numeric(B)` works. `C ~ log(as.numeric(as.character(B))` work too, but `A ~ log(as.numeric(as.character(B))` doesn't, and neither does `A ~ B`.

Comment: You would need to make `mydata` a `pdata.frame` before. And you would need an index for individual and time dimension of your data. Please see the vignette of plm.

Comment: @Helix123 that was it. You can post that as answer and I'll accept it. Thanks!

Comment: You are not showing here any panel `index` and you are going for `pooled regression`. So why not use simple `lm`? why go for `plm`?

Comment: `lm(A ~ log(B), data = test_df)

Call:
lm(formula = A ~ log(B), data = test_df)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)       log(B)  
   -0.04982     -0.04323  
`

Comment: @Zico: one reason could be to be able to use some kind of robust standard errors provided by, e. g.,  `plm::vcovHC`.

Comment: I am not sure why on a non-panel dataset, plm is being applied to get robust std. error. there are few packages which can do it for you even after running lm. like `sandwich` [package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sandwich/sandwich.pdf) in R. please have a look into the [link](http://thomasleeper.com/Rcourse/Tutorials/olsrobustSEs.html)

Comment: also we have a old post from [StackOverFlow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4385436/regression-with-heteroskedasticity-corrected-standard-errors) itself.

Comment: @Zico: This is just a minimal example to reproduce the error. My actual regression had indexes. For some reason (which now appears obviously dependent on the column order of the input files), in some cases the data was loaded correctly and in some others it didn't. So I reproduced the latter with the minimal amount of info possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Helix123 in the comments pointed out that the `data.frame` should be converted to a `pdata.frame`. So, for instance, a solution to this toy example will be:

```
mydata$E <- c("x", "x", "x", "x", "x", "y", "y", "y", "y"); # Create E as an "index"
mydata <- pdata.frame(mydata, index = "E"); # convert to pdata.frame
plm(A ~ log(B), data = mydata, model = "pooling"); # now it works!
```

EDIT:
As to "why" this happens, as Helix123 pointed out in comments, is that, when passed a `data.frame` instead of a `pdata.frame`, `plm` quietly assumes that the first two columns are indexes, and converts them to factor under the hood. Then `plm` will throw an unhelpful error, instead of launching a warning that the object passed is not of the correct type, or that it made an assumption at all.

Comment: if you check plm in details, there is an auto check for index and Checking is done: whether data is a pdata.frame and if not create it. but in this case mysteriously it is not working.

Comment: The first two columns will be assumed as index variables (and those will be converted to factors), see ?pdata.frame